# Give roles in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that makes a channel and gives you a role when you enter a command, I have been trying to get the role part working for quite a while but I always end up with errors after errors- this is my current code-

```py
@bot.command(name= 'playfata')
async def playfata(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Currently Playing")
    if role in member.roles:
        await ctx.send("You already have that role")
    else:
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

and this is the error I end up receiving with this one-

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I tried almost everything I could find on the internet and nothing seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member` has been declared as `ctx.author`

`ctx.author.guild.roles` and `ctx.guild.roles` will get the **same list** of roles, that has **nothing to do** with this problem.

edit: actually, that error is usually raised when your `role` variable returns as None
the name is `case sensitive` so make sure the name is exactly as you have entered, even one letter different will get you role as `None`

Answer (score -1):

There is not much of a problem here. Just a little statement change is needed.

You are using this statement to get the line.

```
role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Currently Playing")
```

Discord.py doesn't work by `member.guild.roles`. At least not anymore. You need to change it to `ctx.guild.roles` and everywhere you need to use this as context can be used anywhere in the command.

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Currently Playing")
```

This would fix your problem.

---

*Tip: Why not use `ctx.reply` instead? I mean it would create an message with reply. Where ever you do `ctx.send` or `ctx.channel.send` just change it to `ctx.reply`. There is not much of a advantage and all but it looks cool. :)*

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work, probably because of the reason mentioned above, but thanks for the `ctx.reply` tip!